# What is the difference between index.openCursor() and store.openCursor()?

Tags: indexeddb

So I have a IndexedDB database whereby I store things by a couple of indexes.

upon fetching those items I can either go by the route of

```
store.openCursor().onsuccess = function(e)
{
    var cursor = e.target.result;
}
```

or I can use get another index from the DB and then open a cursor

```
var index = store.index("indexA");

index.openCursor.onsuccess = fucntion(e)
{
    var cursor = e.target.result;
}
```

These both then itterate through the same collection.

by which I still have to do some comparison by to filter just the results I want.

i.e.

```
if(cursor.value.IndexA == searchValue)
{
    //Found a result for by this index.
}

cursor.continue();
```

So my question is am I missing something, as I feel I really am or is there another benefit to using `openCursor` via an index that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing something. The purpose of the index is to store a filtered listed of values. The filtering has already been done, so you don't need to test against the comparison value as you advance the cursor against an index.

If you want to iterate over all items, use the store.

If you want to iterate over a particular subset of items in the store, use an index, and iterate over the items in the index.

Define your indices ahead of time according to the queries you plan to use.

Edit: actually, to clarify a bit more, an index doesn't exactly filter, it pre-sorts.

Objects in an object store are stored in the order of being inserted or the store's key.

Objects in an index based on an object store are stored according to the index's definition.

Let's say you you want to get only items where propertyX is equal to value1.

If you iterated over an object store, you would be iterating over *all* items in the store, and keeping just the ones you wanted by comparing propertyX to value1.

If you iterated over an index on propertyX, you could use a IDBKeyRange.only as a parameter to openCursor, set to value1, and you don't need to do any test of values iterated. You end up only iterating over the matching values. The indexedDB engine already did the filtering for you. And it does so natively, which is incredibly more efficient, and pretty much the entire point of using indices.

Comment: Right, so without adding the constraint of IDBKeyRange opening a cursor normally against using an index, will get you the same behaviour.
The part I was missing was the ability to add constraint before opening the cursor.